# Convert string to date object in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, date, time

Need to convert a string, which stores the date in format like such: "Apr 23 2014 12:39:17" to a number  or an object; Working with visual studio in a MS-specific environment.

In C++ is there a easy to use function that can achieve this?

I am doing this in order to do a comparison between the string date and now().

Thanks.

Comment: What `now` are you talking about?

Comment: Mmmm.. any now() [Using that as an example of getting the current time]. Basically I take the string off an XML file, which is updated by another program. I want to do a comparison and find out how long ago the XML file was updated.

Comment: Well, there is `std::chrono` if your compiler supports it, otherwise `boost`, C functions, or OS calls.

Comment: strptime() since you mentioned Unix ?

Comment: There is _loads_ of reference material online about the handling of dates in C++ using Boost and other libraries. Can you demonstrate that you've done some research, and tell us what the problem is with what you found?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Meh; To be honest. I was being very lazy. It's a bad day for me. I'm reading through Boost now. I'll figure it out and post my solution here afterwards.

Comment: You could use strftime()

Comment: [Formatting dates with stringstream](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22142372/3309790) may help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was un-lazy in the end.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found for my problem.

To clarify: A string representation of a date needed to be converted into some sort of date object, so that I could find the difference between 2 dates.

This works on MS VisualStudio2010 & uses the microsoft classes. (Basically; It won't work on a unix box!).

```
// Create 2 COleDateTime objects:
COleDateTime DateTime1;
COleDateTime DateTime2;

// 'Get' 2 string dates:
BSTR time1 = L"Apr 24 2014 09:20:20";
BSTR time2 = L"Apr 23 2014 12:39:17";

// Parse the string dates into the date objects (See! Its alot easier then I thought!)
DateTime1.ParseDateTime(time1);
DateTime2.ParseDateTime(time2);

// Calculate the time difference with a COleDateTimeSpan Object...
COleDateTimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime2 - DateTime1;

// Create integer with the difference in time in seconds...
CString str = timeSpan.Format(_T("%S"));
int differenceInSeconds = _tstoi(str);
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Good stuff. This is of course only half an answer as it doesn't fit the question tags (being MS-specific), but there you go.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Updated the question. It should be more informative for anyone who wishes to use it to learn. I always mean to go back to questions I ask and make them neat; This is the first one I've got around to. Sidenote: The code I was writing above is now with the 'customer' and they are happy with it. First time I've been allowed to share my code with our 'customers'. Good day!

Comment: Nice one :) 